# Passing null to the overridden method when the difference between methods is the parameter subtype

Tags: java, oop, jvm

OUTPUT:B

Why does virtual machine call this method `f(null){System.out.println("B");}`?

Why not `f(null){System.out.println("A");}`

```
public class Test{

    public static class A {}
    public static class B extends A {}

    public void f(A a) {System.out.println("A");}
    public void f(B a) {System.out.println("B");}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().f(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: please review your formatting ...it not clear

Comment: seems we need to dig out the spec again...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method with **most specific parameter** type is called. Thats the rule 
This is from [JLS section 15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.5)

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.